# Docker Container - Missing properties file

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.13 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY invoke.go ./
COPY readproperties.go ./
COPY config.properties ./


RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o server

FROM fishtownanalytics/dbt:0.19.0
USER root
WORKDIR /dbt
COPY --from=builder /app/server ./
COPY script.sh ./
COPY jaffle-shop ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./server"]
```

When I run the Docker image and the Go server (invoke.go has the main which calls readproperties function) references the config.properties, I get the following error:

```
2021/04/21 22:27:29 Go: starting server...
2021/04/21 22:27:29 open config.properties: no such file or directory
```

How do I copy the properties file ?

It has `key=value` pairs

Building and running this way:

```
docker build -t sample:v1
PORT=8080 && docker run -p 9090:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} sample:v1
```

All the files are in the same location as the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: How are you building the image and launching the container?  Can you show the code that tries to read the properties file?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the details.

Comment: Is this your full Dockerfile? If not, are you using a multi-stage build perhaps?

Comment: @colm.anseo I have added the entire Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your properties file is copied to the "builder" stage - where it is not needed during compilation. Instead it should be copied to the final stage.

Update your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM golang:1.13 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY invoke.go ./
COPY readproperties.go ./

#
# REMOVE:
#
# COPY config.properties ./


RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o server

FROM fishtownanalytics/dbt:0.19.0
USER root
WORKDIR /dbt
COPY --from=builder /app/server ./
COPY script.sh ./
COPY jaffle-shop ./


#
# ADD:
#
COPY config.properties ./

#
# OR: copy it from the builder stage
#
#COPY --from=builder /app/config.properties ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./server"]
```